# Angular - Shared html formatter function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my project, I have a function that is used to set the CSS class of an element.

This function is declared in different components that need to apply dynamic CSS and each time I have to make a change in the function, I have made the change on all the ts file as well.

What is the proper way to have a single function that works in HTML component files?

Should I create a service?

The function works in this way:

**component.ts**

```
GetStatusClass(_s: string): string {

    var c = "";
    switch (_s) { 
      case "NEW":
        c = "label label-primary";
        break;
      case "CONFIRMED":
        c = "label label-success";
        break;
      case "CANCELLED":
        c = "label label-danger";
        break;
      case "CONCLUDED":
        c = "label label-default";
        break;
    }
    return c;
  }
```

**component.html**

```
h4><span class="{{GetStatusClass(offert.offertStatusCode)}}">{{offert.offertStatus}}</span></h4>
```

Thanks to support

Comment: Seems like a good use case for a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

Comment: Use a service and inject it wherever you need that functionality

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen , it sounds good! Provide the response... I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good use case for a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes). The code could look something like this:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'statusClass'})
export class StatusClassPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(statusCode: string): string {
    switch (statusCode) { 
      case 'NEW':
        return 'label label-primary';
      case 'CONFIRMED':
        return 'label label-success';
      case 'CANCELLED':
        return 'label label-danger';
      case 'CONCLUDED':
        return 'label label-default';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }
}
```

And in your template use it as follows:

```
<span class="{{offert.offertStatusCode | statusClass}}">{{offert.offertStatus}}</span>
```

Probably a little bit cleaner still to put the values in a map or object to eliminate the `switch` statement.